# Resizing a label in a custom cell in code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a label in a custom cell and it won't resize. Here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let myCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("privatecell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourPrivateControllerCell

    myCell2.barfront1.frame.size.width = 200
    myCell2.barfront1.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return myCell2
}
```

I know I can set the width by adding a constraint but the label will be a different size for every row. The code works for a normal view controll view but doesn't seem to work for a tableview cell/row. The actual code will be:

```
myCell2.barfront1.frame.size.width = myCell2.barback1.frame.size.width * percent
```

but I cant even get the label to resize to 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constraints and connect the constraints with @IBOutlet like this. Of course you have to put this in the YourPrivateControllerCell.

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelWidth: NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
```

Then call the following method will be change the width of you label.

```
labelWidth.constant = 200
```

Good Luck.

Comment: My solution actually doesn't work, because as you scroll, the width constraint for the label changes and goes out of wack. Your response is the correct solution. Thanks Jason!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Instead of setting a width for the label I added a layout width constraint. Code:

```
myCell2.barfront1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myCell2.barfront1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: myCell2.barback1.frame.size.width * barwidth1[indexPath.row] * 0.01))
```

Now the label is a different size for every row.